# OSX: Quit app correctly upon logout

Tags: objective-c, macos

Every time I am trying to log out the current user (not Fast User Switchting!) I get a message from macOS (excuse me if its not exactly the message, I am getting it in german): "Unable to logout, because application "com.my.app" does not quit".

What do I need in order to avoid this? I currently have this in my AppDelegate:

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    return NSTerminateNow;
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    return true;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver: self
                                                           selector: @selector(receiveLogOffOrShutdown:)
                                                               name: NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification object: NULL];
}

-(void) receiveLogOffOrShutdown: (NSNotification*) note
{
    [application stop:nil];
}
```

What I have observed for example is that `receiveLogOffOrShutdown` is never triggered. As well as `applicationShouldTerminate` never triggers a breakpoint.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is your app showing a modal window?

Comment: No. Just a normal window

Comment: Does Quit from the Dock menu work?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSApp.terminate method

**Objective C**

```
-(void)relaunch {
    int processIdentifier = NSProcessInfo.processInfo.processIdentifier;
    NSString *path = [NSBundle mainBundle].executablePath;
    NSArray *arg = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",processIdentifier], nil];
    [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:arg];
    [NSApp terminate:self];
}
```

**Swift**

```
func relaunch() {
        let processIdentifier: Int32 = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().processIdentifier
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().executablePath! as NSString
//        let myPath: String = "\(path.fileSystemRepresentation)"
        NSTask.launchedTaskWithLaunchPath(path as String, arguments: ["\(processIdentifier)"])
        NSApp.terminate(self)  
    }
```

**func terminate(sender: AnyObject?)**
When invoked, this method performs several steps to process the termination request

Hope this help you.

Comment: can you translate this to objective C?

Comment: Okay. wait for a minute.

Comment: i guess i understood it now. the problem is, WHERE shoudl I call terminate? I replaced my stop with the terminate, but it did not help...

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. The question isn't how to terminate the app, the question is why the system can't quit the app.

Comment: @Nidhoegger So can you Please elaborate more about the issue so that we can easily figure out what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: What infos are you missing? When I click Apple -> Log out <username> I get a message box that tells me that OSX cannot logout the user as "MyApplication" is blocking beeing terminated.